# How to prevent super intelligent humans from existing in a world defined by genetic engineering?

Tags: science-fiction, genetic-engineering

In a setting where genetic modifications are common, and genetically designed babies are all the rage, what could possibly prevent people from just... making uber intelligent humans?

I dont want this to be the direction the story goes, and I fear I'm too stupid to grasp about the repercussions on a society that could do this.

Comment: Couldn't you just say that the brain is just to complex to effectively improve. I mean we i real life do not know a lot about how the brain functions compared to other organs. So if they mess with the brain they always screw up because it is to complex.

Comment: Read about super intelligent people we actually have. They rarely matter all that much! See Trump as the perfect example that other things often matter more... connections and motivations, for example. Also because our world is so incredibly complex that more intelligence does not give you all that much more of a relative advantage. The high IQ people may just get lost in their analysis too much. They are good at _certain_ tasks, but not that much better overall in life.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock By sheer coincidence this evening I got a fortune cookie with the following fortune: *If our brains were simple enough for us to understand, we would be too simple to understand them.*

Comment: Reminded of Dune's mentats, especially in the context of all the genetic manipulation going on in the story.

Comment: Could you define more clearly what you mean by "super intelligent"?  Do you mean "No One as smart as Newton, Darwin, Etc.?"  Or do you mean "No One Significantly Smarter than them?" Or do you mean "No One as Smart as the Best AI 20-40 years from Now?"  Or even more intelligent than that?  These are wide ranges with very different answers to address them.

Comment: No more worries about super-intelligence, if you kill all the smart people.  If that's distasteful, just remember that intelligent people (*specifically* women, since they're the one with intelligence and have to bear the children) have much fewer children.

Comment: @RBarryYoung like smarter than einstein or newton. unnaturally smart. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 22):

**What causes intelligence?**

To the best of my knowledge, scientists working with the human genome have not ascertained which genes or combinations of genes result in different levels of "intelligence".  It is possible that genetics is not the primary cause of intelligence in a person, that development of high intelligence is partly/mostly a result of developmental influences from conception onwards.  Or it could be the interaction between particular genes and particular stimulii - for obvious reasons it is practically impossible to conduct ethical trials on humans to determine the causality.  There is no reason to believe that this question will be resolved in the foreseeable future, even with a long term effort by an unethical research program.  So, the first option you have is the entirely believable situation where the genetic engineers can determine hair colour, eye colour and other physical aspects but still do not know *how* to engineer intelligence.

The second option ties into the question of definition that I avoided in the previous paragraph - what is intelligence?  IQ is a measure of how well a person can complete IQ tests or similar activities.  Yet the membership of Mensa and the leading scientists, political and economic leaders of world are sets with limited overlap, meaning that high IQ does not necessarily correlate with success in today's world, or tomorrow's.  Just as many military forces are notorious for getting ready to fight the last war, the people counted as intelligent today may not be considered to be so in a generation.  Then there is the fraught question of measuring emotional intelligence, which is definitely useful when interacting with other humans but is IMO even more likely to result from developmental rather than genetic influences.  So, even if "intelligence" could be engineered, not everyone will have every type.

The final option is that IQ-type-intelligence may not be the greatest thing to have.  I recall a science fiction story (but not its name!) where genetic engineering was widespread and it was recognised (in the setting) that high intelligence tended to correspond to lower happiness.  Parents who wanted their children to be happy deliberately did *not* select for extremes on the intelligence scale.

Comment: Not sure if the third option would work - there would be a number of societies where the decisions would be made by the government rather than the child's parents and where happiness of the genetically-engineered geniuses would not be a major concern (although maybe OP's world is more utopian in this respect). The first option seems very likely though - our own world is probably not that far from being able to do human genetic engineering but afaik we still have absolutely no idea how intelligence 'works' on a genetic level.

Comment: @GiantSpaceHamster the kind of government that is going to assert its primacy over what kind of children parents have to raise is possibly going to prefer "sheeple" to geniuses who are raised by parents who dislike the government overriding their wishes.  As you say, though, it depends on what type of government or other authority gets to make the decisions or influence the parents.  (For influence, think about how different real-world religions might prefer people who *don't* think too hard about their doctrine.)

Comment: @GiantSpaceHamster To expand on the "sheeple" comment, Unhappy people tend to go down one of two paths.  Either they become rebellious to create circumstances that they think will make them happy, or they become depressed and therefore unproductive or even suicidal.  Chronic unhappiness is in fact a very big deal for any government.

Comment: That said, if governments are calling the shots, making a few sad super thinkers would be very worth while, so that alone is not a good solution if you are trying to make sure there are no or negligibly few super smart augments.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 You don't need many geniuses, you don't even _want_ that many, someone has to sweep the sidewalks. So most population will indeed be 'sheeple' (maybe even genetically manipulated sheeple? Now we're really getting into 1984 territory here). However a few geniuses to design tanks and fighter jets and maybe surveillance bugs will certainly be valuable, even if they won't be as motivated as they could be. Worst thing they could do is refuse to work for you, if I was a dystopian totalitarian government I'd certainly take that chance.

Comment: The second paragraph would be better if it didn't equate intelligence with Mensa membership. Wikipedia says that Mensa admits people with scores in the 98th percentile, implying ~100 million people worldwide are eligible, but it has only 150,000 members, so even if it's true that "the membership of Mensa and the leading scientists, political and economic leaders of world are sets with limited overlap", it tells you more about their lack of interest in Mensa than about their intelligence. Most people never take an IQ test, much less try to join Mensa.

Answer (score 15):

Are you sure that genetics is all it takes to make intelligent humans?

Einstein, Mozart, Newton, Euler, Fermi, Leonardo da Vinci, Gauss have all had siblings and progeny, yet we don't have a lineage of geniuses in the same way as we have with race horses.

Environment plays also a big role in developing a very intelligent person. Take a toddler Leonardo or anybody else from the short list above and, instead of nurturing his skills, send him mining sulfur or coal from a tender age. You won't get a super intelligent man, you will get an undereducated individual who just fight for day to day survival.

Comment: Intelligence has a genetic factor, with multiple control genes. The examples you used are akin to someone rolling 18 on all 3d6 six times. Imagine only five genes (it's more) control intelligence. If it's codependent, it means only 1:64 odds of inheriting. Each extra gene increases the odds by factors of 2 and 4 respectively. If it's recessive, 1:1024. The comparison with race horses is disingenuous.

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica - race horses' desirable characteristics are _also_ subject to multiple control genes.  Assuming that inheritance is a one-in-a-thousand chance is assuming that _every one_ of those control genes must fall a certain way to produce an intellect a cut above the average, which is a peculiar assumption to make given what has already been said about how little we know about genetic determinants for intelligence.  I think the comparison is apt.

Comment: Actually, it works just like a racehorse.  If you don't train a horse, it won't be winning any medals no matter how good its genes are. Likewise, if you don't train a genetic genius, they won't become exceptional... but there is a very clear difference between students with a strong aptitude for a subject, and one without it.  If you don't have the genetic aptitude, then you will likely never master the thing no matter how much you train.

Comment: @jdunlop it is the **claimant's responsibility** to prove the claim. Not make affirmations based on vague *"if the number is unknown, then it can be whatever I want"* assumptions. The Stack Exchange guidelines demand precision and accuracy. Such fallacious claims are detrimental to the construction of a trustworthy knowledge database.

Comment: The Euler family was most certainly a lineage of geniuses.  Intelligent people who procreate will most certainly have a much higher chance of having intelligent offspring than two not-so-intelligent people.  You just don't see the genius offspring because there are so many people in the world, and faux-egalitarianism makes it gauche to talk about them.

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica I don't think he's saying that there is an issue with the number of possibilities, he is saying that there is a logical flaw in your assumption that only one combination of genes will result in a desired outcome.  With complex genes, you can have a million possible gene combinations that express your intelligence, and of that group there may be a 100,000 combinations that represent a distinct advantage.  So even if you don't land on that perfect 1:1,000,000 combination you want, parents in the top 10% are much more likely to produce kids in that top 10%.

Answer (score 10):

I would generally say there are several reasons that could make **genetic engineering of intelligence very hard**.

Here are some suggestions i came up with:

1. **It is considered unethical:** You could just say that this kind of engineering has been banned for ethical reasons. These could be enforced by some big organizations that generally don't like the idea of screwing with the brain.
2. **The brain as a "black box":** Just refers to the fact that the brain is just very complex and we don't completely know how it works. We can compare it to an A.I. where you can't just edit it as you have no idea how it works. So any edit of the brains DNA would just completely mess things up.
3. **Neurons are too sensitive:** In the real world brain cells are not really the most resistant to damage. I mean your brain is the first thing to start dying if you have no oxygen. So messing up its DNA could just straight up kill every one it is done with.
4. **Intelligence is complex:** Similar to what **KerrAvon2055** suggested. Intelligence is just partially of your education. So you can't just make people hyper intelligent but just fast learners.
5. **Natural limits:** This is the most pseudo scientific of them all but still somewhat grounded in reality. It could be that its impossible to improve neurons too much because they are already on the limit of what they could be biologically capable of. I mean for sure you can maybe produce a genius but he would just not be a god among man.

*Note:English is not my primary language so please excuse any grammar or spelling errors.*

Comment: As a rule, genetic engineering (if realistic) has to occur in utero or earlier, so point #3 is kind of irrelevant.  The neurons will not have developed before they are modified.

Comment: (Also, the brain is not the first thing to start dying if you have no oxygen.  You start losing cardiac muscle first.  The brain is just more sensitive to damage.)

Comment: I am no biologist so yeah probably but the point is that the brain still starts to die relatively fast without oxygen.

Comment: That may be the point, but it's not the point (or assertion) you made in your answer.  (Also, the ability for a cell to resist oxygen starvation is independent of its tolerance of chromosomal damage.)  Also, the fact that the statement was wrong is independent of the fact that, again, the neurons would not _exist_ prior to their DNA being modified, so you wouldn't see cell death, because there would be no cells.

Comment: The point was that it may be possible that due to the sensitive nature of Neurons it is quite possible that messing with DNA related to them to much might have some severe consequences. Sure it is not maybe not 100% scientifically accurate but most would not even notice such a minor detail to begin with.

Answer (score 9):

### It creates dangerous and crippling mental illness

The classical concept of a Intelligence being a quotenant is wrong.  There is no such things as a super smart human, just people whose brains are optimized to think in specific ways.  Every kind of thinking that the brain can do that is not allisticlly balanced comes with a price that makes functioning as a human being more difficult.

If for example you were to enhance the prefrontal cortex, you could make a human who has super self awareness and would be a philosophical prodigy and expert planner, but they would also have a much harder time accepting inevitabilities, dealing with incomplete data sets, and committing to a single course of action.  They will obsess over every possible future outcome causing them to suffer from crippling anxiety, paranoia, and indecisiveness.  Such a person could be very successful in a perfectly predictable world, but all the messiness of real life makes this level of prefrontal thinking self-destructive.

If you enhance the left side of the brain, a person could become extremely analytical, methodical, and logical.  They would become a prodigy with math, facts, and system design.  But what you are left with is a person who hyper fixates. They will suffer from OCD and/or ADHD making it difficult to switch between tasks as needed, and they will have a hard time disregarding erroneous things they've learned. Your superhuman might technically become a genius in regards to one or two special interests, but as a whole, they will struggle to branch out enough to explore a more useful breadth of knowledge.

If you enhance the right side of the brain, the person will become super creative, empathetic, and emotional.  They could become prodigy artists or master manipulators. But too much creativity leaves you with a person who struggles with maintaining a grasp on reality.  Even if they are lucky enough not to outright hallucinate: imagination and delusions will overlap causing them to make up thier own entire version of reality, or they will be so quick to imprint thier desires on thier experiences that they become dangerously optimistic.

### What if you try to enhance everything?

While we might think that enhancing the whole brain together will give you a faster, more capable, allistic brain, it is much more likely that you will get a person with all of the strengths of super intelligence and all of the drawbacks that naturally co-exist with those strengths.  Your super geniuses will be become such nervous, hyper-fixated, delusional wrecks that they will be incapable of functioning in useful ways.

So, what if you try to eliminate the issues by reducing other things?  If you inhibit the amygdala, you can tone down how much the person cares about things so that they are no longer crippled by the various kinds of fear that come with over thinking... but, without being able to feel bad, it means you take away the ability to understand right from wrong.  It also does not take away the delusions, fixations, and paranoia it just makes them more manageable; so, what you are left with is a psychopathic paranoid schizophrenic with savant autism.

In short: you get [KHAAAAN!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khan_Noonien_Singh)

### The Inevitable Outcome

Super intelligence in your world has probably been experimented with, but the outcome is so frequently bad for both the individual, and society as a whole, that it will not take society very long to make it illegal.  Once illegalized, intelligence augmentation will become extremely rare in your setting, and when you do see it, it very rarely goes well.

If the law allows for it at all, it will probably be used only to correct for neurological deficiencies to bring an autistic or damaged brain up to normal function, and not a bridge farther.

Comment: There's a common perception that high intelligence is associated with mental illness, but apparently (from quick web search) this is not true.  At least not among humans. Perhaps this question is not asking about humans.

Comment: @arp Within 1 standard deviation, no: you can be "smart" and not mentally ill.  But the question is about super-human intelligence.  As you cross into >2 standard deviations above normal, you start looking at "gifted" mindsets.   These people almost always have impairments caused by "to much of a good thing".  Gifted teachers have to be specially trained to handle these side effects because they are seen in nearly all gifted children.

Comment: I agree that studies show that high IQ correlates to better outcomes, but it is more accurate to say that mental disorders will reduce your ability to perform well on an IQ test.   Many of those disorders are represented by too much activity in certain parts of your brain.  Part of what makes a high IQ is having an optimized brain, not an enhanced one; so, my point is if you just try to enhance the brain to operate at a higher capacity like you would with a muscle, you can reduce that person's functionality.

Answer (score 6):

### Lethal Side Effects

Human growth is a very slow, tricky, and complex process.  Any significant deviations from this process will cause unintended side effects, and in the case of super intelligence the side effects can be particularly bad like coma, becoming brain dead, and death.

One of the reasons why it takes so much longer for humans to reach maturity versus other animals is that we have to dedicate lots of calories to our brain.  As such making the brain more powerful is going to put a greater strain on the limited resources to mature a human.  Depriving the body of critical resources to make a better brain can quickly cause health complications leading to death.

But even if the body (through more genetic engineering) could provide all the resources needed to make a better brain, it could easily be established that neurons can only handle so much and super charging the brain can result in entire portions of the brain burning out resulting in symptoms similar to what stroke victims experience.

Answer (score 5):

**Idiot Savants**

[image]

The more intelligent people become, the less able they are to handle the day to day things. They can work out prime numbers in their heads but can't buy a hotdog.

Sure, they could engineer more intelligent people but they're less able to function in society. Being smarter doesn't make them more capable, resilient, successful or even happy.

There's a price to pay and sometimes it's not worth it.

Comment: Pretty sure Marilyn vos Savant - the woman that 'Savantism' was named for - is doing quite well. Being intelligent doesn't always come with crippling drawbacks. That said, every 160+ I know (about 5 of them so far) has a variety of psychological problems. They're all functional, but not necessarily the most stable crayons in the box.

Comment: @Corey: I doubt that savantism is named for Marilyn vos Savant. The word itself predates her by at least 90 years (see e.g. [this 1855 use](https://books.google.com/books?id=QNIdAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA297&dq=savantism)), and I assume its modern sense comes from *idiot savant* (which also long predates her; see e.g. [this 1888 use](https://books.google.com/books?id=qzJYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA280&dq=idiot-savants)) or a similar expression. As you more-or-less note, the word doesn't seem to describe her at all.

Comment: @Corey I have to disagree.  I've worked with gifted kids, both as a parent, and as a teacher, and all of the gifted kids I've met have similar functional disabilities, regardless of if they are idiot savants or not.  Kids in the 120-130 IQ range can go either way, but once you start to cross into 140 range, pretty much every gifted kid struggles with understanding things like imprecise language, they hyper focuses on things that makes getting other more important things done first impossible.

Comment: They gets so attached to rules, that they have a hard time negotiating social dynamics and letting go of misconceptions.   They get decision paralysis over what should be very simple, every day choices.  The issue with  being that smart is that it requires intense focus, and intense focus comes with natural consequences.

Comment: My experience is quite different. The presence of a very high IQ 'tends' to relate to lower social or emotional traits but only because intelligent kids with low EQ tend to stand out. Two of the most intelligent people I know do not come across as 'typical high IQ' simply because they have good social skills.

Comment: In another lifetime ago, I dealt with a QC on a legal matter. Guy was scary smart but couldn't drive. He'd be so busy thinking about things, he had accidents. Had to hire himself a driver. Luckily, being a QC, he was loaded and could afford to.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe they simply lack the understanding?

In today’s world we hardly understand how the brain actually works. We understand even less how certain genes affect it. Not to mention tweaking them in ways which leads to desirable outcomes.

Other body changes are much easier and tangible and could probably be done in the near future (ethics concerns aside). Simple stuff like: Changing eye colors, changing limb lengths, increasing muscle mass by increasing testosterone production, being able to grow a full beard, removing the ability to grow hair completely …

Heck, even adding the tail back in or growing a 6th digit on the hands is easy in comparison to messing with the brain.

Comment: This. Creating a superintelligent human would involve not just designing a better brain but also all the molecular pathways to build it.

Answer (score 3):

Intelligence is expensive.  For a standard-model human, about 20% of the energy budget goes to keeping the brain running.  Try to boost that beyond human norms, and you'll start running into problems of blood flow, oxygen supply, cooling, and so on.

Sure, careful gene selection will give you a baby with a fair chance of developing into the next Einstein, but going *beyond* Einstein is a major bioengineering challenge.

Comment: As for Einstein himself, he was not so much exceptionally smart as he was exposed to just the right combination of life experiences to have just the right day dreams to consider things other people did not consider.  When you read about what things inspired him, it is clear that had he not wandered by a window washer on ladder, taken the train, or showed up for school on just the right days...

Comment: had he not had enough free time to just sit and think his life experiences through, then he would have never realized the foundational principles of general relativity. In fact, due to the Flynn effect, Einstein only had an estimated IQ of about 120-130 by today's standards; so, chances are you personally know people who are genetically smarter than Einstein... just not lucky enough in life to stumble upon the same epifanies.

Answer (score 2):

They see genetic engineering as a way to prevent sicknesses, and to optimize lifespan and physical skills. They do not see it as a way to increase intelligence.

Their reason is more philosophical for that: they believe, people with genetically increased intelligence would not be the same people as they originally had been.

However, they have no problem the integration of brain with chip and enhance intelligence on this way. Their only task is to make these chips easily detachable, replaceable, and, of course, open source.

Comment: Sooo, to hack a person's brain, all you have to do is  replace thier brain chip while they sleep?  Replaceable, sure, but you may not want it to be too easy...

Comment: @Nosajimiki That is a story. I f-ly hate this whole brain chip idea and I believe the country where they are normal, should be cleaned by atomic bombs. But that is my opinion. Here it is about a story.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Btw, I know some about this hack thing. I have no chance to crack your local router. In the first phase, these chips will only serve as some type of "augmented reality", i.e. with these chips you will instantly know things. But the end... *"And that no man might buy or sell, save he that had the mark, or the name of the beast, or the number of his name."*

Comment: Hacking my local router across the internet is hard, yes... but if you had access to my house, simply replacing it with one that gives you back-door access is so easy that the average teenage kid could figure it out.   As for open sourcing it, that makes it even that much more dangerous.  While open source can lead to software with fewer bugs, it also makes it way easier to make evil twins.  So, not only could I replace your chip with an infected one, but I could make sure the new one runs the old software so you can't even tell you've been hacked.

Comment: You are mistaken.  My problem is not with the open source or the chips in the brain (from a world building perspective, ethically brain chips are awful). It is the "easily detachable" part that I have a problem with.  Imagine how much more dangerous online dating becomes if your date can just swap out your brain chip and suddenly get access to your bank account, passwords,  or worse, use it to exert control over you opening up huge potential for easy human trafficking.  I'm just saying that they would make people too vulnerable to make since, especially if you whitebox the technology.

Comment: @Nosajimiki That is entirely irrelevant to open source. But anyways it can be solved by cryptology (signatures and encryption). But you know what is at the end? You won't need brain chips et al, only a tattoo. That will be the *number of the Beast*. If you don't have this tattoo, you won't be able to buy and sell anything. Possibly the tattoo will be some chip, but more likely tattoo. Scripture says "stamp on head or hand".

Comment: A tattoo does not address the hyper intelligence issue.  Your original point of the chip was not about government tracking or the sign of the beast, it was about augmenting intelligence without genetic engineering.  As for signatures and encryption, you do not seem to understand the risk of physical access in cyber security.  Let's pretend you have a permanent implanted chip to contain your signature, and a separate replaceable chip for running your apps.  This is the same issue as having access to someone's phone.

Comment: If I steal your phone, and it is encrypted, then I can not read what is on your phone, but if I steal your phone, and place your sim card into an identical, jailbroken phone and give it back to you, then the first time you go to use it, it can steal your biometrics and/or access pin.  Then I don't need to break your encryption because your new phone will send me everything I need to just log into your old phone exactly the same way you would.

Comment: Only this is way worse because the hacked chip has direct access to your brain; so, I don't need to wait for you to "log in".  I can just access your brain directly for all the credentials I need (because your brain is not encrypted).  My comment about open source is that it is way easier to build such a jailbroken phone that does this when the OS is open source than when it is not.

Comment: In most respects, I agree with you that open source is typically better.  I'm just saying that this is an edge case where it represents an added security risk.

Answer (score 2):

### Firstly because genetic engineering is a public health program (not a 'do it yourself' home hobby). And secondly because there are risks involved - hence the public oversight.

Your question states that genetic engineering (GE) is in *wide spread use*.  It's also a highly complex and delicate process that needs to be conducted in a clinical setting by trained medical professionals. So just like other complex medical procedures GE  procedures are part of the National Health System like maternity and pediatric services or indeed any other medical treatment requiring external interventions.

Because it's widely used and effective this also means GE is paid for by in full or part by health insurance and people undergoing the procedure attend registered clinics for the procedures and have the process documented in their medical records. The national health system then collects and collates those records for national epidemiological purposes and medical statistics. Just like it does with all your other trips to the doctor. Detailed records are kept.

This leads to the second point though which is that just like there other procedures that have been banned for safety reasons genetic modifications to intelligence are banned as well. This is because to date, no-one has been able to get the process 'right' i.e. repeated attempts in the past have resulted in patients with high intelligence but also with serious complications such as mental illness (i.e schizophrenia, manic depression etc) or pathological conditions like psychopathy or sociopathy or severe narcissism (the 'mad' genius syndrome). The result? Has almost always been tragic for all involved with life long on costs for the patient, their families and the society as a whole. Sure sometimes (on rare occasions) someone might 'luck out' and come out the other end with all the benefits of increased intelligence and none of the downsides. But in reality? Only a tiny % of people who underwent GE for intelligence did so successfully. Maybe in the future with more research that would change, who knows. But for now? It hasn't. So the treatment is banned, no exceptions! **EXCEPT PERHAPS?**: Procedures involving children diagnosed at a young age with development delays where the technique just tends to raise IQ back towards the normal range and because of brain plasticity etc any side effects aren't nearly as severe. (But still still present perhaps?)

P.S. Maybe there are a few highly illegal and expensive underground clinics where you can spin the the roulette wheel and take your chances but don't blame them if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are assuming that if something is good, more of it must be better.

In reality, such is true only over a limited range.

Outside any thing's effective range, things fall apart.

Answer (score 1):

In speculative fiction and silver-screen tales, there's a trope that gets trotted out time and again: crank up a person's IQ, and you've got a villain plotting from their lair. But when we turn the lens on real-world intellects, the picture shifts. Consider the Einsteins, the Newtons, the von Neumanns of history. These minds were light-years beyond their contemporaries, but their orbits didn't gravitate toward the throne room.

These intellectual giants were often introspective, choosing to dance with complex theories rather than wade into the muck of power struggles. For them, the whole power play was more of an oddity, a human quirk that drew a bemused glance rather than any serious ambition. It's a bit of a paradox, but towering intelligence often comes with a keen sense of the triviality of power games.

So let's dispense with the Hollywood narrative—the lone genius villain, his finger poised over the "destroy the world" button. That's not how it works. The Manhattan Project, for instance, wasn't a cabal of rogue geniuses; it was a concerted effort by many, overseen by those with perhaps more practical savvy than pure intellectual firepower.

And think about ventures like OpenAI. It's not a mastermind's solo act but a symphony of brilliant minds. Progress, particularly the technological kind, is a team sport, not a gladiatorial bout.

True, if we ever find the key to unlocking superintelligence without eroding our humanity, those individuals could indeed seem formidable. But history suggests they'd be far less interested in leveraging their intellect for dominance. It's the power-hungry, those who see every opportunity as a commodity, that are the real concern. They are the ones that could derail our collective journey, not the superintelligent, who are likely to be preoccupied with grander, more esoteric quests.

Answer (score 1):

Sex makes things weird. As in - the selecting gender, can fetishize anything and thus deform the result in the process. One selection criteria turns you into a flight handicapped https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird-of-paradise.

The other selection criteria turns you into a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrot#Intelligence_and_learning.

They share parts of the environment and take totally different direction.
So all it takes, is the selecting caste, sex, ai, technician, to not like intelligence- and after a while its gone. And if the selected for criteria is handicapping intelligence, it wont come back, until the technology breaks down - and you are stranded the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

**Frame challenge: they made "superintelligent" humans, but the practical changes were negligible.**

Many futurists and AI theorists throw out the term "superintelligence", but there is little solid analysis of exactly what that term would *mean*, in practice.  It's almost always described by analogy: "Picture a being as smarter than humans as humans are smarter than dogs!  Or plankton!" This analogy is usually delivered breathlessly.

But there simply may not be enough "conceptual space" left for intelligence to fill to allow that kind of enhancement.  Because human beings are already pretty damn smart.

We are closing in on a "Theory of Everything" in physics.  If that is achieved, human beings will have used their intelligence to determine the fundamental nature of the universe.  A hypothetical "superintelligence" is going to figure out...what else, exactly?  Science fiction writers hand-wave over this and have superintelligences that can manipulate dimensions with thought, and achieve telekinesis or similar magical abilities...and we simply have no reason to believe that any of those things are *possible*, regardless of level of intellect. And if they aren't, then superintelligences that make us look like dogs just are not possible, because there's not enough left for additional intelligence to *do*, to create a gap that large.

It is very likely that superintelligent humans, and superintelligent AIs for that matter, will be able to do the kinds of things that humans already do...somewhat faster.  Or without computational aids.  And that's really just not much of a change.  It would make some workplaces *look* somewhat different, and would speed up prosaic advances in some fields, but you might not have to assume that it would disrupt whatever plot you're trying to craft *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few limitations I can foresee, going around these limitations will essentially require redesign of the biology.

1. There is a limit to neuron fire rate. Since we are built from biological foundations, we will never be as fast as a computer. Thus, there is constraint on upper intelligence for humanity. Larger brains requires more coordination, which in turn will slow down processing time. In this case there might be incredibly intelligent people who could solve almost any problem. That they will be very very slow.
2. Like computers our brains require cooling. Larger brain means much larger head to facilitate cooling. But, larger head means larger body, which will require more mental capacity to control as well as larger body means heart has to pump more blood more quickly. While this could go on for a while, there would be an upper limit on the size of humans due to gravity. This will also affect life span. Putting a limiting factor on the human intelligence.
3. As larger ANN requires more training, more intelligent individuals often require longer to mature. Super intelligent individuals might never mature, making them very difficult to deal with. Thus policy makers may decide to stick to an upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

These are some ideas I had at first:

- The scientists/engineers who did the genetic engineering are refusing to help other people to become clever enough to replace them because they are now immortal and want job security
- Intelligence can't be easily controlled by genes
- After previous experiments around modifying intelligence wend disastrously wrong (either too clever or unintelligence), it was outlawed
- Super intelligence comes with problems such as the brain consuming too much oxygen and energy that the entire body dies
- There are already systems (perhaps AGI) that make the need for intelligence redundant